# delete incoming write event after calculations in firebase functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have an app that uses firebase, the whole stack pretty much, functions, database, storage, auth, messaging, the whole 9. I want to keep the client end very lightweight. So if a user comments on a post and "tags" another user, let's say using the typical "@username" style tagging, I moved all of the heavy lifting to the firebase functions. That way the client doesn't have to figure out the user ID based on the username, and do everything else. It is setup using triggers, so when the above scenario happens I write to a "table" called "create_notifications" with some data like

```
{
  type: "comment", 
  post_id: postID, 
  from: user.getUid(), 
  comment_id: newCommentKey, 
  to: taggedUser
}
```

Where the taggedUser is the username, the postID is the active post, the newCommentKey is retrieved from .push() on the comments db reference, and the user.getUid() is from the firebase auth class.

Now in my firebase functions I have a "onWrite" trigger for that specific table that gets all of the relevant information and sends out a notification to the poster of the post with all the relevant details. All of that is complete, what I am trying to figure out is... how do I delete the incoming event, that way I don't need any sort of cron jobs to clear out this table. I can just grab the event, do my needed calculations and data gathering, send the message, then delete the incoming event so it never even really exists in the database except for the small amount of time it took to gather the data.

A simplified sample of the firebase functions trigger is...

```
exports.createNotification = functions.database.ref("/create_notifications/{notification_id}").onWrite(event => {
  const from = event.data.val().from;
  const toName = event.data.val().to;
  const notificationType = event.data.val().type;
  const post_id = event.data.val().post_id;
  var comment_id, commentReference;
  if(notificationType == "comment") {
    comment_id = event.data.val().comment_id;
  }

  const toUser = admin.database().ref(`users`).orderByChild("username").equalTo(toName).once('value');
  const fromUser = admin.database().ref(`/users/${from}`).once('value');
  const referencePost = admin.database().ref(`posts/${post_id}`).once('value');

  return Promise.all([toUser, fromUser, referencePost]).then(results => {
    const toUserRef = results[0];
    const fromUserRef = results[1];
    const postRef = results[2];

    var newNotification = {
      type: notificationType,
      post_id: post_id,
      from: from,
      sent: false,
      create_on: Date.now()
    }
    if(notificationType == "comment") {
      newNotification.comment_id = comment_id;
    }

    return admin.database().ref(`/user_notifications/${toUserRef.key}`).push().set(newNotification).then(() => {
      //NEED TO DELETE THE INCOMING "event" HERE TO KEEP DB CLEAN
    });
  })
}
```

So in that function in the final "return" of it, after it writes the finalized data to the "/user_notifications" table, I need to delete the event that started the whole thing. Does anyone know how to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

First off, use `.onCreate` instead of `.onWrite`. You only need to read each child when they are first written, so this will avoid undesirable side effects. See the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#trigger_a_database_function) for more information on the available triggers.

`event.data.ref()` holds the reference where the event occurred. You can call `remove()` on the reference to delete it:

`return event.data.ref().remove()`

Comment: If I change it over to onCreate would I still use the same path and still have the {notification_id} param?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this is through calling the `remove()` function offered by the admin sdk,
you could get the reference to the `notification_id` through the event, i.e `event.params.notification_id` then remove it when need be with `admin.database().ref('pass in the path').remove();` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of Firebase, use:
`return change.after.ref.remove()`